# Filter JSON based on startdate and enddate

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2015-06-19",
    "operator": "ums.dam",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Sales",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-17",
    "operator": "ums.rdl",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Media",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-17",
    "operator": "ums.dam",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Other",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-16",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Press",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-15",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "Troubleshooting",
    "subType": "Service",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-15",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Sales",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-15",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Other",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-04",
    "operator": "ums.jxh",
    "type": "Account Maintenance",
    "subType": "Add/Remove Feature",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-04",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "Account Maintenance",
    "subType": "Add/Remove Feature",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-04",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "Troubleshooting",
    "subType": "Service",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-04",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Other",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-01",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Manual Activation",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-06-01",
    "operator": "ums.djf",
    "type": "General Query",
    "subType": "Manual Activation",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus odio purus, sit amet semper leo congue eu. Aliquam erat."
  }
]
```

The JSON comes from external sources and will be dynamic in production, but all sources will have this same structure.

The user will have three inputs:

1. first input to choose JSON source (removed for demo purposes)
2. second input to choose start date to begin returning JSON data (for example **2015-06-01**)
3. third input to choose end date to end returning JSON data (for example **2015-06-19**)

Here is the form HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <form id="search" role="form" style="border:0">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li><strong>From Date</strong></li>
          <li>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dateFrom" />


          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li><strong>To Date</strong></li>
          <li>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dateTo" />

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="getJsonSrc">Search</button>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Row -->
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$("#getJsonSrc").click(function() {
  var $table = $("#dataTable"),
    $startDate = $("#dateFrom").val(),
    $endDate = $("#dateTo").val(),
    $jsonSrc = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77979/demo.json"; //for demo only - in production this will come from 1st input val()

  /* This is the code that is not working */

  $jsonSrc = filter(function(i, fromDate, toDate) {
    return ($jsonSrc.date < $startDate && $jsonSrc.date > $endDate)
  });

  $table.bootstrapTable("destroy");
  $table.bootstrapTable();
  $table.bootstrapTable("refresh", {
    url: $jsonSrc
  });
});
```

Essentially what I want is when the user clicks search the page gets the JSON source URL, but only returns data between the inputted dates (including entered dates). The JSON is then outputted into bootstrap data table.

I typically provide a jsFiddle example, however I had no way of getting a fiddle to read an external JSON file, so hopefully a codepen example is okay :)

http://codepen.io/lordtubington/pen/GJOVpy

Note: I realize there is a filter extension for bootstrap table https://github.com/lukaskral/bootstrap-table-filter however this filter extension works AFTER the data has been fetched. My users will be requesting files with thousands of records, I can't have them fetching all the records and then applying date filters :)

Comment: This isn't really a javascript question if you want the server to filter.  By definition, your client side javascript can only filter them after downloading.  You'll have ti implement some sort of web service; how depends on your server side tech stack.

Comment: Really? I've seen many other examples of javascript filtering on the client side here on SO, just haven't found a solution that works for me yet. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172289/filtering-a-json-array-using-jquery-grep and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Both those examples are filtering after the fetch, as well as the example below.  They are just doing the filtering prior to loading it into the table, but the data is being downloaded to the client.

Comment: please do not use [bootstrap] as tag. that's another thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the code by this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJdMxv

The changes I made: I loaded the json by jquery, created date objects for the start date, end date and the obj date, then created a new Array and pushed all matched dates inside the array.

```
$("#getJsonSrc").click(function() {
  var $table = $("#dataTable"),
    $startDate = new Date($("#dateFrom").val()),
    $endDate = new Date($("#dateTo").val()),
    $jsonSrc = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77979/demo.json";

  $.getJSON($jsonSrc).success(function(data) {
    my_array = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var this_date = new Date(data[i].date);
      if ((this_date >= $startDate) && (this_date <= $endDate)) {
        my_array.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log(my_array);

    $table.bootstrapTable("destroy");
    $table.bootstrapTable();
    $table.bootstrapTable("refresh", {
        url: my_array
    });
  });


});
```

Comment: Looks like it's working in the console, but how do I get it in my bootstrap table? :) When I replace `url: $jsonSrc` with `url: my_array` on line 30 of your codepen JS panel I get error `Uncaught ReferenceError: my_array is not defined`

Comment: That's because the $table.bootstrapTable functions starts a long before creating the my_array.
You have to run the bootstrapTable functions after the new array is created, or run a function after the my_array is created, so put the bootstrapTable functions after the console.log(my_array)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. `$table.bootstrapTable("refresh", {url: $jsonSrc});` does come after the `console.log(my_array)` =/. Can you please update your codepen to show what you mean?

Comment: Doesn't work. I think it's turning the JSON source into an Array, so I'm getting error `404 cannot find url:[Object, Object, Object]`. I updated my pen http://codepen.io/lordtubington/pen/GJOVpy so you can see the error in the console.

Comment: This will not work because the option: 'url' asks for a url.
You should find another option (in the documentation) that says data or something and then use the my_array

Comment: Oh right :) Sorry I've been at this for a while. I changed `url` to `data` (per the documentation) but it's still not working. Seems to be an js object now instead of json. I'll keep trying but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't need `JSON.stringify(my_array)` and I needed to use the `load` option instead of `data`. Below is the working code:

```js
$("#getJsonSrc").click(function() {
    $("#dataTable thead").show();
    var $table = $("#dataTable"),
        $startDate = new Date($("#dateFrom").val()),
        $endDate = new Date($("#dateTo").val()),
        $jsonSrc = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77979/demo.json";

    var my_array;
    $.getJSON($jsonSrc).success(function(data) {
        my_array = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var this_date = new Date(data[i].date);
            if ((this_date >= $startDate) && (this_date <= $endDate)) {
                my_array.push(data[i]);

            }
        }
        $table.bootstrapTable("load", my_array);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form id="search" role="form" style="border:0">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li><strong>From Date</strong>
          </li>
          <li>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dateFrom" value="2015-06-17" />


          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li><strong>To Date</strong>
          </li>
          <li>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dateTo" value="2015-06-19" />

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="getJsonSrc">Search</button>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Row -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table id="dataTable" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="5" data-page-list="5, 10, All" data-search="true" data-search-align="left" data-striped="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-sort-name="date" data-sort-order="desc">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="date">Date</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="operator">Operator</th>
            <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="type">Type</th>
            <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="subType">Sub Type</th>
            <th class="col-xs-5" data-field="message">Message</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```