# Filtering a json object with array of values using jquery grep

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to filter JSON result using jQuery grep.My JSON result look like this:

```
 var data = { "items":[
  {
      "Name":           "Name 1",
      "City":      "city1"
  },
  {         
      "Name":           "Name 2",
      "City":      "city2"
  },
  {
      "Name":       "Name 3",
      "City":      "cat1"
  }
]}
```

Filter this JSON with array of Name example:

```
var Name= ["Name 1","Name 2"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)** to filter the items array

```js
var data = {
  "items": [{
    "Name": "Name 1",
    "City": "city1"
  }, {
    "Name": "Name 2",
    "City": "city2"
  }, {
    "Name": "Name 3",
    "City": "cat1"
  }]
}
var name = ["Name 1", "Name 2"];

var res = $.grep(data.items, function(v) {
  return name.indexOf(v.Name) > -1;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 3) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or with **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
var data = {
  "items": [{
    "Name": "Name 1",
    "City": "city1"
  }, {
    "Name": "Name 2",
    "City": "city2"
  }, {
    "Name": "Name 3",
    "City": "cat1"
  }]
}
var name = ["Name 1", "Name 2"];

var res = data.items.filter(function(v) {
  return name.indexOf(v.Name) > -1;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 3) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the string array from existing object array using $.grep so first use $.grep for filter the object and then use $.map for get the specific output from the result object like below code will help you.

**Filter the object using $.grep**

```
var data = {
    "items": [
  {
      "Name": "Name 1",
      "City": "city1"
  },
  {
      "Name": "Name 2",
      "City": "city2"
  },
  {
      "Name": "Name 3",
      "City": "cat1"
  }
    ]
};

var objret = $.grep(data.items, function (n, i) {
    return n.Name == 'Name 1' || n.Name == 'Name 2';
});
```

Now you have result object in the objret variable now convert the object result to your string array out put using $.map like :-

**Get OutPut**

```
var array = $.map(objret, function (value, index) {
    return [value.Name];
});
```

so in the array have your required output.

Answer (score 0):

I think is the same questione exposed here:
[question] [Filtering a json array using jquery grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172289/filtering-a-json-array-using-jquery-grep)

However json array are like string, or you get an array from that or u can access it only like string.
Use jquery grep to recreate the array then access it via index to compare value