# How to get a single object in an array to a JSON model

Tags: javascript, json, model, odata, sapui5

I have a JSON model /details with 4 objects. I want the object based on the key :month.

```
   Object
   oData
   details:
   Array[4]
   0:Object
   1:Object
   2:Object
   3:Object
    editable:false
    key:"date"
    removeable:false
    value:"Day: TRUE, Night:False"
   4:Object
    editable:false
    key:"month"
    removeable:false
    value:"August"
```

The following is the code

/view

```
 var viewModel = that.getView().getModel();
 var viewModelData = viewModel.getData();
```

Comment: loop over the object in the array looking for the key month

Comment: Working with objects is pretty easy. Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Look at this grep method of JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172289/filtering-a-json-array-using-jquery-grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query the object directly. You have to loop and search like so:

```js
var viewModel = that.getView().getModel();
var viewModelData = viewModel.getProperty("/details");
var month = getObjectByKey(viewModelData, "month");

function getObjectByKey(a, key){
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if (a[i].key === key){
    return a[i];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I get the model with the property, but I am not able to bind it.sap.m.Table({  columns: [
                    new sap.m.Column({
                        header: new sap.m.Text({
                            text: 'key',.
                        })
                    }),],
                items: {
                    path: '/details',
                    template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                        cells: [
What should be the path for binding to table

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to have a table with each detail object as row displaying their key and their value? Or do you want to display an array contained in the key="month" object in the table?

Comment: I want to display each detail object with key = "month" as row displaying their key and their value

Comment: I have made a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448141/how-to-bind-items-to-a-controller-based-on-json-property